# Most efficient technique to climb

Tags: war-thunder

What is the most efficient technique used to gain altitude with a fighter or any other plane? I have seen many ways of doing it, the simplest being a standard climb by accelerating forward at a slightly upward angle.

I have also used a series of [Immelmann's](http://wiki.warthunder.com/index.php?title=Combat#Immelmann) to achieve the desired altitude.

Are there any other techniques that use a different game mechanic to achieve a certain altitude the fastest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of experimentation and research, I've come to the realization that every time you change direction, or use the control surfaces at all. You sacrifice energy to change direction.

Therefore the most efficient technique would be to have change direction as little as possible. So pick a straight line up into the clouds and accelerate.